# Debian access point is detected, but provides no Internet access

Tags: debian, networking, ip, access-point

I am use Debian sid. I want to share my network (ppp0) via AP (Access Point) to my mobile device.
This is my configuration.

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` :

```
# WiFi Hotspot
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
#Access Point
ssid=PERSIB_nu_AING
hw_mode=g
# WiFi Channel:
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=anggabaedeuh
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` :

```
option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-update-style none; ddns-updates off;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.0.200 192.168.0.229;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
}
```

and here my other config for calling AP :

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.0.1
hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

In my mobile device, the SSID is detected. but when I try to access the Internet, I can't connect.
What's wrong with my configuration?
On my PC, I also installed Slackware-current and Ubuntu 12.04,
and configured them in the same way, and it worked.

```
#uname -a
Linux angga.id 3.11-2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.11.10-1 (2013-12-04) i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you ping the mobile device when it detects the SSID?

Comment: yes I use putty for login to my ssh in debian. I can login. but I cant conect to internet.

Comment: Did you flush iptables with `iptables -F` and `iptables -t nat -F` before you added the masquerade rule?

Comment: I was, but not work :(..